# How to distribute array elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an array:

```
A=[1,2,3]
```

I want to distribute these elements in two people and want to print all the possible combinations using python** .

For example:

```
[(1,2)(3)] ,[(1)(2,3)]....
```

Here first one is getting 1,2 and second one is getting 3.

in second combination first one is getting 1 and second one is getting 2,3

One more important thing is that:

If `[2, 3] [1]` is one combination then `[1] [2,3]` is also a different combination , we have to print that also

I want to get all these combinations.

```
EDIT 1-  For better understanding i am adding one more example.

A=[ 1,2,3] 

 Here is the all  desired combination.
[
[] , [1,2,3]
[1,2,3] ,[]
[1], [2, 3]
[2, 3], [1]
[1, 2], [3]
[3], [1, 2]
[2], [1, 3]
[1, 3], [2] ]
```

Comment: Is every array going to be length 3 and only 2 people every time?

Comment: @Jab The length of array is not fix but it will be distributed in between only two  people every time.

Comment: Is mixing up the order of the array allowed? For instance: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` **->** `[1, 4]`, `[2,3]`?

Comment: @Jab yes . one more thing i want to add is that for  [ 1,2,3,4]---> [1,4],[2,3] is one combination then [2,3] [1,4] will also be print  as a combination.

Answer (score 2):

I must prepend this and say that it is not very optimized, however it's quite stable, and should work with any length of `a`.

```
from itertools import chain, permutations
from  pprint import pprint

def devider(x):
    dev = round(len(x)/2)
    return x[:dev], x[dev:]

def sorter(x):
    r = []
    for i in x:
        if isinstance(i, tuple):
            r.extend(list(i))
        else:
            r.append(i)
    return r

a = [1, 2, 3]
x = list(set(chain(*[[i, i[::-1]] for i in map(devider, permutations(a))])))
pprint(sorted(x, key=sorter))
```

Output:

```
[((1, 2), (3,)),
 ((1,), (2, 3)),
 ((1, 3), (2,)),
 ((1,), (3, 2)),
 ((2,), (1, 3)),
 ((2, 1), (3,)),
 ((2,), (3, 1)),
 ((2, 3), (1,)),
 ((3,), (1, 2)),
 ((3, 1), (2,)),
 ((3, 2), (1,)),
 ((3,), (2, 1))]
```

The `pprint` module and `sorter` function is only there for representation purposes, so that it's easier to see that each wanted permutation is represented.

---

If you want to include `((1, 2, 3), ())` and `((), (1, 2, 3))` you can simply do it manually and use the `list.extend` method to add them to the list:

```
z = [(tuple(a), ()), ((), tuple(a))]
x.extend(z)
```

Comment: sorry i think you didn't get my question the output will be [
[] , [1,2,3]
[1,2,3] ,[]
[1], [2, 3]
[2, 3], [1]
[1, 2], [3]
[3], [1, 2]
[2], [1, 3]
[1, 3], [2] ]   changing position of elements will not consider as a combination

Comment: @Akashnitter I've updated the answer to try to include the exclusive versions as well. Is that more like the way you want it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`more_itertools.set_partitions`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.set_partitions)

```
>>> from more_itertools import set_partitions
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> for item in set_partitions(A, 2):
    print(item)

    
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[2], [1, 3]]
```

**EDIT:** To get the reversed order as well, you could do:

```
>>> for item in set_partitions(A, 2):
    print(item)
    print(list(reversed(item)))
```

Prints:

```
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[2, 3], [1]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[3], [1, 2]]
[[2], [1, 3]]
[[1, 3], [2]]
```

Comment: The thing is that if [ 2, 3] [1] is one combination then [1] [2,3] is another combination , we have to print that also.

Comment: @Akash nitter I edited the reply to include this case.

Comment: Hey bro  thanks but your answer is just printing the reverse order.   but i want this combination in the same list so that can access these combinations.

Comment: @Akash nitter Just append them to a list instead of printing them, straight forward.